# Detect LaTeX class name

Tags: latex, introspection

I'm working on a LaTeX package which might need to do some things differently depending on the class that's being used.  I'm wondering if there's a way to auto-detect or test the document class.

One could certainly look up the class files and test for the existence of a specific macro defined by that class, but is there a smarter way?  I looked at the definition of the `\ProvidesClass` macro and can't see if it saves the class name anywhere except `\@currname`.  I believe `\@currname` is just the name of the current package or class being read.

Basically I want to execute

```
\author{\longauthorname}
```

in the `article` class but

```
\author[\shortauthorname]{\longauthorname}
```

in the `beamer` class.

Comment: Could you inspect a *feature* of the problematic class(es) instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which document class is being used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After refining my question I'll show how I answered it.  Along the lines of what dmckee was saying.  Just test for the functionality.

```
\ifcsname beamer@author\endcsname
  \author[\shortauthorname]{\longauthorname}
\else
  \author{\longauthorname}
\fi
```

`\ifcsame` is available on all e-TeX builds and is documented (along with other ways to check if a command is defined) [here](http://tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/generic/FAQ-en/html/FAQ-isdef.html).

You can't check for the actual signature of the `\author` macro (i.e., does it take an optional argument?) but you can check for some of the auxiliary macros defined to implement optional arguments.  `\beamer@author` is one of those in the `beamer` class.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should not check the name of your class (or version).
You should check the functionality.

For example, class `article` has `\@titlepagefalse` and
class `book` has `\@titlepagetrue`. 
Write

```
\if@titlepage yes \else no \fi
```

and recognize the presence of title page.

Comment: I tend to agree with you.  The reason I want to know the class is that in some classes I use the `\author` macro takes an optional argument and in some it doesn't.  So I guess the best thing to do is check for the existence of whatever auxiliary macro the class sets up to give `\author` that different signature.

Comment: What's the high-level LaTeX command to check if a macro is defined?

Comment: `\author` is `\gdef\@autor{#1}`, isn't? To check if a macro is defined write `\ifx\command\undefined undefined\else defined\fi`

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy test for the loaded document class: `\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{<true>}{<false>}`

Short example:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\longauthorname}{foo}
\newcommand{\shortauthorname}{bar}


\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{%
    \author[\shortauthorname]{\longauthorname}
}{
 \author{\longauthorname}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for revisiting this ancient question!